# cannot run ecs container on ec2 instance in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, private-subnet

I'm trying to run the container of a service I created with AWS ECS. But the ecs agent on the EC2 instance fails to retrieve some configuration from an AWS managed s3 bucket:

```
Failed to pull image ...........dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/........:latest: error pulling image configuration: Get https://prod-eu-west-1-starport-layer-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/.......: dial tcp 54.231.141.131:443: i/o timeout
```

the instance is running in a private subnet, that I configured using [this tutorial](https://www.topcoder.com/blog/aws-container-services-private-subnets-tutorial/).

I can curl `www.google.co.uk` from the instance, but I cannot ping/curl `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`, which I can from my computer and from a bastion on the public subnet associated to the same VPC.

The issue looks similar to the unsolved question [ECS agent can not successfully pull image from ECR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376413/ecs-agent-can-not-successfully-pull-image-from-ecr) but my problem is just about retrieving that configuration from that s3 bucket.

Answer (score -1):

You need to whitelist/ allow outbound access to https://prod-eu-west-1-starport-layer-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com from your ecs instances because it is used internally by AWS to manage ECR image layers.

Check the below references for more details : 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-minimum-s3-perms.html
https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-ecr-user-guide/issues/8#start-of-content

Comment: Please add some explanation here. Links may be moved somewhere or become invalid. StackOverflow prevails! :)